# Nested Nunjucks For Loop

Tags: html, template-engine, nunjucks

I am trying to write a nunjucks template that loops through an outer array and populates columns, then loops through a nested array to make rows in each column.

So, my data structure looks something like this:

```
var data = [
    {
        'type' : 'fruit',
        'list' : ['banana', 'kiwi', 'strawberry']
    },
    {
        'type' : 'vegetables'
        'list' : ['tomato', 'carrot', 'zucchini']
    }
]
```

I want to create an html doc that looks like this:

```
<div>
    <span>fruit</span>
    <ul>
         <li>banana</li>
         <li>kiwi</li>
         <li>strawberry</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div>
    <span>vegetables</span>
    <ul>
         <li>tomato</li>
         <li>carrot</li>
         <li>zucchini</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have tried making a nunjucks template that looks something like this:

```
{% for category in data %}
    <div>
        <span>{{category.type}}</span>
        <ul>
           {% for thing in category.list %}
            <li>{{thing}}</li>
           {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

But, for some reason, I can't access the inner variables. I don't really have access to the inner for loop.  I have looked on stack overflow, and through their documentation, but can't find anything about nested for loops.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. [http://jsfiddle.net/xmojmr/751fw7h5/](http://jsfiddle.net/xmojmr/751fw7h5/) works as expected. They only thing I had to "fix" was to **add comma** after 'vegetables'

Comment: Was this ever resolved? If so I'd really appreciate hearing what worked. Struggling with this very issue for hours now.

Comment: I just used your code as a boilerplate and it couldn't possibly work any better. The *only* thing I had to add was a comma right after `'vegetables'` in your `data` array.

Answer (score 2):

Missing colon in json might cause the issue...

So instead of this

```
'type' : 'vegetables'
```

try this

```
'type' : 'vegetables',
```